# Example Tarski-finite | What does it mean for an element to be minimal in terms of inclusion?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am studying elementary set theory at the moment and came across the Tarski-finite definition.
I my lecture it was stated as:

> Let $a$ be a set. $a$ is finite iff every non-empty $b\subseteq \mathcal{P(a)}$ has a minimal element in terms of the inclusion $\subseteq$

So I tried to just work it out for the set $\{a,b\}$.
I know that
$\mathcal{P(a)} = \{\{\},\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$
Now I take $b\subseteq \mathcal{P(a)}$ for example $b=\{\{a\},\{b\}\}$.
What does it mean that b has a minimal element in terms of inclusion?
Since I don't know whether $a$ is in $b$ or anything like that.

Comment: See [Minimal element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements): **not greater than** any other"In general $\le$ is only a partial order on $S$. If m is a maximal element and $s\in S$ then it remains possible that neither $s\leq m$  nor $m\leq s$. This leaves open the possibility that there exist more than one maximal elements."

Comment: It means $\exists c\in b\,\forall d\in b\, (d\subseteq c\implies d=c).$ That is, $c\in b$ and no member of $b$ is a proper subset of $c.$

Comment: So $\{a\}$ and  $\{b\}$ can be both minimal elements? Thank you very much!!!